# Use of open interval to define local maxima and minima

Tags: calculus

We use a point on open interval to find local maxima and minima. Can we use closed interval in the definition. If no why ?

Comment: If one used the closed interval, say $[0,1]$, then it would appear that $f(x)=x$ had a local maximum at $x=1.$